# How one should live a peaceful life knowing this fact that there is no meaning of life?

Tags: society, life, socrates, meaning-of-life, naturalism

So I am going through the philosophical path and I think I am deep into it nowadays.
That old question "What is the purpose of living when we are going to die one day" was eating my mind but Then I found you have to give meaning to life, Now I want to know from experts and experienced philosophers how one should live a life when he knows about this world and He knows everything is just random event, Nothing matter at all.

Therefore, should I live the life that I want to do and the way I want to live? But the problem with this kind of life is I can't survive because this life demands curiosity and thinking and if I do that continuously then I don't want to earn money because in my view money is just papers created by us, why should I invest my life after this thing? But I am enjoying my life living this way, I do not care about anyone, I do, I sing, and I play whatever I want because there is no pre-defined meaning of life, You give meaning.

Or should I live a balanced life, Act fake in front of corporate people so that can stay in the corporate world, and Fake smile so people can think you are happy and living a good life, But this life is good till when we are outside, If we are inside our home and spending time with yourself alone, You will find you are being fake.

What is the way of living then?

Since when I am into philosophy I started to see this life from the very different perspective, I think only a few people see from this perspective, it is kind of Enlightenment, After this, I have no desire for anything, Not for money, Not for any materialistic thing, No greed, No jealous , I found myself quite isolated and I started enjoying my solitude , I can stare a single leaf hours and hours and be thinking about nature and observe nature , When I am seeing anything I am finding that this is something amazing but people find it normal , If I am seeing a flower , I am amazed , happy to see how nature have shaped this flower , How many chemical reactions happed during this growth , How amazing nature is, How complex structure this flower has and I am curious about knowing the nature science behind flower , But same time if someone will see that he will say, It's just a flower nothing else , That's the difference I am finding myself little isolated , I am not enjoying their talks or anything , I am more towards curiousity But I am not able to find what is the best way of living life , Should i continue with those people who see that flower as "Just Flower" or should i go into isolation ?

Should I force myself to give an aim for life?

Or if I choose without aim life ( as there is no predefined meaning of life) then What is the purpose of living and wasting time on planet?

Comment: I think if you consider that other people are even more interesting than nature, you may begin to find yourself on a more sustainable path toward peace.

Comment: Slaves have purpose and meaning in their lives. Free men make their own.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Personal life advice is off-topic on this site, we are taking questions that are more or less objectively answerable based on existing philosophical literature.

Comment: Perhaps this could be of some assistance:  https://archive.org/details/frenchexistentia013201mbp

Comment: See 'If everything ends one day why don't we end it today?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90072/if-everything-ends-one-day-why-dont-we-end-it-today/90081#90081 & 'What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017

Comment: & 'If all of us are going to die one day why should we care about the feelings and emotions of others?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/if-all-of-us-are-going-to-die-one-day-why-should-we-care-about-the-feelings-and/50146#50146

Comment: How do we align the *river* with the *city*? Who knows, I don't know, God knows!

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means the expert experienced philosopher that you are looking for but it seems like you answered your own question here:

> ...I do, I sing, I play whenever, whatever I want because there is no pre-defined meaning of life, You give a meaning.

I think this is literally the best you can do.

It seems to be common for people to think that if existence is not eternal, and if there is no supreme creator then everything is meaningless and there is no point to living. All I can say is that I do not understand this line of thought at all. To use your own examples, why would my enjoyment of a flower depend on eternal life, or absolutes enforced by some god being? (not that the OP is necessarily comparing their position to a theistic one, it is simply a common dichotomy that I expect many people to be familiar with)

I share your belief in an essentially random world with no inherent meaning. Rather than being depressed by that I find it to be exhilarating and liberating. I am overjoyed to know that I am not here for any purpose.

You are one of the most rare things in the universe: a human living on this planet. The fact that it only lasts a short while, and that there is no ultimate reason or purpose does not diminish the experience in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> How one should live a life when he knows about this world and He knows everything is just a random event.

The answer depends on the philosophical school you ask. You did not specify one, and I find the most applicable school for such questions is that of the sceptics.  A skeptic would ask how you *know* that life has no meaning beyond what you give it, and that everything is a random event.  Can you actually know that?  Or are you just assuming it because you think there's no other option?

The natural result of questioning such things is to consider one of three possibilities:

- There is no meaning for life beyond that which we make
- There exists a meaning for my life, but I am not yet aware of it.
- The concept of knowledge is flawed in this respect (a radical skeptic's perspective)

The first two possibilities suggest that if you know an action is good w.r.t the meaning of life which you make, and provides the potential to uncover an external meaning for life if one exists, then you can know that action is "good."  The third possibility points out that maybe we need to question the word "know" in the previous sentence.

Studying philosophy tends to satisfy both of those scenarios.  Of course, it's up to you to decide if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a professional philosopher, but I think there are some obvious points to make on your question.

> Should I live a life what I want to do and the way I want to live? But the problem with this kind of life is I can't survive because this life demands curiosity and thinking and I do that continuously then I don't want to earn money because in my views Money is just papers created by us, Why should I invest my life after this thing?

Well, if you have no money at all, you won't have much opportunity for curiosity and thinking. An empty stomach isn't very helpful for either, and will naturally shift your priorities to getting something to eat. So the reason to earn money is to allow you to have the opportunity for curiosity and thinking.

Of course, that means that you don't strive for more money than you need, but I think that is a good thing.

Also, note that curiosity and thinking versus earning money need not be mutually exclusive. Scientists are *paid* for applying curiosity and thinking.

> But I am enjoying my life living this way, I do not care about anyone,

I strongly doubt that you are not caring for anyone. Imagine everyone you know would be gone. Wouldn't you miss some of them? Then you care about them. Would you be happy if they were angry at you? Probably not. Therefore you care for having a good relationship with them. This means necessarily to care to some extent for *their* desires, as otherwise they will not see a reason to care for yours.

In the end, everything you do sooner or later has a back effect on you. If that back effect is something you don't like, it's probably a good idea to not make that decision to begin with, as you'll pay for it later. Not necessarily with money, but with entering a less pleasant or even non-pleasant situation, or a situation where you cannot even approximately live the life that you want to live. Of course, it may be that not making that decision has an even worse effect on your future life, in which case making that decision is the right thing to do.

In short, there are constraints on your life that come from outside of yourself. Living your life the way you want to really means to live a life as close to the one you want to as possible under external constraints. And sometimes you have to make a trade-off between having a better life now, and potentially having a better life later.

Answer (score 0):

It is through your interactions, mental and physical, that you can achieve your goal (peaceful life). Perhaps this is the answer to both your primary question and your last question.

Consider the egoist and altruist.

It is worth noting that most people change their goals and behaviors during the course of their life.

Comment: I like the answer, but I think it needs references.  This allows the answer to point readers beyond it. Rather than asserting something quote some philosopher as saying essentially the same thing with a reference.