# Why should we care about anyone?

Tags: ethics, camus, absurdism

If we take the World as absurd - without any meaning or end result, and believe in no such thing as God or afterlife (taking Camus' stance in Myth of Sisyphus), why should anyone, fundamentally, care about anything or anyone? Of course, in transactional relationships reciprocity is the norm, and therefore it makes sense to engage in transactional care (social/psychological needs). But is there anypoint in *really* caring about anyone? What arguments can we provide for caring in the face of absurdism?

Comment: See [The Paradoxes of Camus’s Absurdist Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/#ParCamAbs): "as Francis Jeanson (1967) wrote, isn’t absurdist philosophy a contradiction in terms, strictly speaking no philosophy at all but an anti-rational posture that ends in silence?"

Comment: i mean it just depends on what you think absurdism amounts to. if it amounts to moral anti-realism then sure -- you are under no rational obligation to care for anyone (yourself included). if not, then we can truthfully say that your lack of concern makes you morally deficient etc. if that doesn't bother you -- then you are a "practical skeptic" about morality. but i don't see how anyone can be interested in absurdism and unconcerned with what is true...

Comment: If we take the World as meaningful, with an end result, and believe in God or afterlife, why should anyone, fundamentally, care about anything or anyone *then*? The fallacy is in assuming that *value* can somehow be derived from facts about how the world is. [It can not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem). The same question can be asked in response to "because God". Any value or meaning is a choice, and it can be made in the face of God or end result just as well as in the face of the absurdity. But neither God, nor end result, nor absurdity make it happen.

Comment: @Conifold I understand your point, and take it as an answer to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If all of us are going to die one day why should we care about the feelings and emotions of others?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/if-all-of-us-are-going-to-die-one-day-why-should-we-care-about-the-feelings-and)

Comment: One way of thinking about it is that even if there is no reason one *should* care about anyone else, one may find that they still do anyway. If there was an ethical argument that we should not preserve human life, we may find what we want differs from what an ethical theory says we *should* do.

Comment: "Ants" need to care ...every day. "Gods" don't need to care, but they care (everyday) and don't care (everyday)... Now(!) it depends, wether you are more "ant-philosopher" or "gods-philosopher"!;)

Comment: If we took the world as absurd, how could we "logically considerate"? And if there was no "meaning" (at all), how could one use the word "if" (any word...)?;)

Answer (score 9):

One of the weaknesses of the Western philosophical tradition - something that Existentialism and Absurdism tried to address — is that Western philosophy discounts psychology (broadly put). It implicitly presumes that things must have *reasons* in the analytical, intellectual sense, and that leads to some unnatural conclusions. For instance, one might wonder why people bother to eat complex, carefully prepared, diverse meals. All one needs for continued existence is a bland mush of protein, carbohydrates, fats, and assorted nutrients, and one could save a heck of a lot of time and effort by (say) eating meal replacement bars from WalMart for every meal. But people don't; they like complex, diverse, 'rich & tasty' foods, and are willing to spend large portions of their lives seeking such out. Of course, someone could say that people seek out good food because it's *pleasurable*, but that's just a pseudo-rationale. 'Pleasure' is not an analytical concept; things are pleasurable because they are pleasurable, and for no other reason. It's a built-in bias of our biology, not a moral choice.

Caring for others, and being cared for in turn, is pleasurable. While we could get all of our basic social and personal needs met through simple transactional relationships, most people become bored with the shallowness of it, and seek out deeper and more complex relationships.

Thinkers like Camus and Sartre were focused on the 'objective' meaninglessness of existence almost to a fault; they failed to look at (at least as far as I recall off hand) how the act of making meaning out of life is intrinsically pleasurable. Your question boils down, I think, to a question of why we should make meaning out of life if life has no intrinsic meaning. And the only real answer to that is that we are happier when life has meaning.

Comment: "Thinkers like Camus and Sartre were focused on the 'objective' meaninglessness of existence almost to a fault" +100 _Meaning_ is subjective and should not necessarily be searched in objective realm.

Comment: [It is disputed whether there are any pure analytic statements at all](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/). But even if there are, the claim, that one should base one's conclusions or philosophy solely on those, is restrictive and problematic.

Answer (score 4):

Sartre proposes that caring is a reality of human psychology from which we cannot escape (along with psychoanalysis and a raft of feminists, but he is the biggest-name philosopher who put it clearly).  In doing so he goes back to the Cynics.

This question is almost always asked this way around, by solipsists, by skeptics, by absurdists, by other forms of nihilists, etc.  This is *not* the way it was originally proposed by this school.

Diogenes' first question was how (and why) to *deface currency* -- how to determine *what **not** to care about*.  That is a much more useful question.  But it is not *whether to care* it is *when to care* because we basically have no choice.

Humans as animals automatically care about far too many things: their next meal, the next generation, the opinions the others around them, how they might be remembered after death, whether they themselves might somehow survive death, how much to fear that, what death is...  Piles and piles of automatically arising attachments.  Since we are social creatures, we also project those concerns onto those around us and empathize with them. [Babies symbolically get even with abstract shapes that treat other abstract shapes badly.](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/07/190729111225.htm)

It is hard work not to care.  Much harder work than choosing something to care about.  Why do so?  It is *that impulse* that one needs motivation for.

And how would you get the motivation to sustain that hard work unless you chose to *care about it*?  If you take the world as absurd, why fight your biology that hard?

Comment: I understand your point of view. But I am interested in arguments in favour of caring if we *accept* Camus' position on absurdism.

Comment: The Cynics aren't pre-Socratic

Comment: His decision that Sysiphus is happy seems not to compete with this view. Sysiphus is doing what it has become his nature to do: he is serving his own psychology.   If he were consigned to an endless, thankless task involving the service of other people, he would eventually come to care about them -- because that would be as much in the nature of his task as handling the rock is in the one assigned.  Because we really have no choice but to create sense out of senseless conditions, even if we realize that is what we are doing.  Satre is including Camus in the problem he is solving here.

Comment: @b a You are right, in one sense: they were contemporaries and he defended Socrates from Plato. But then by that standard Parmenides is not pre-Socratic... And we don't say that.  These contemporaries' philosophies were not formed in relation to Platonism, and that puts them before the start of Western Philosophy in earnest. To avoid a dispute over words, I will omit the reference.

Answer (score 3):

If 'the World is absurd - without any meaning or end result' then if *caring* is absurd, so is *not-caring*. 'Why should I care about anyone?' and 'Why shouldn't I care about someone - or everyone?' - both questions are themselves absurd as are any answers to them. 'Why should I care?' has no special salience; it's just itself one more absurd question among all the others. This is not my viewpoint but it appears to be a logical consequence of the position you define.

A further logical consequence is that my answering the question is an act of absurdity, but then so would be my worrying about this absurdity.

Comment: That seems like a really shallow portrait of the philosophy of absurdism. It is transcendent or objective meaning that's missing, not local, contextual, constructed meaning, or the concept would eat it's own tail.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. It will be useful to whoever reads my answer in future. I agree that I give a 'quick' answer that turns, I think correctly, on a logical point. I accept that a developed philosophy of absurdism would require a longer and deeper response. Best - Geoff

Comment: @CriglCragl I would argue its not shallow at all. According to Camus, one of the way absurdity arises when one must choose and reason is unable to tell the _best_ choice.

Answer (score 2):

This text will be long, yet will give you one scientific way to look at it.
When reading, please turn off the emotions for a minute. Also lets look in a big scale, instead of looking individually - that said, lets try to answer "why should human species care?".
Then we can extract the individual answer for ourselves.

### Possible choices

In the end, your question all boils down to the statement "nothing really matters" why should we care, right ?
And that could be interpreted as "we can live in any way we want, without considering or caring about others". But that's only one way of interpreting it.
To see the whole picture, lets go through all possible combinations of `living`/`dying` and `considering`/`not considering` others in our actions. Then we will (try to) find a root cause, and then see where we are and where we go.

The possible combinations are:

1. We choose to **die**.
2. We choose to **live**, **without considering** others.
   If *everyone* lives this way, chaos may begin and we all eventually die - just because someone else wanted it, didn't care or didn't consider others. Thus chances of dying are higher. It may contradict the choice itself - we still may die whereas we chose to live.
3. We choose to **live**, **by considering** others.
   But "do whatever we want" gets partially limited when "considering others"...
   Thus, we give up a part of our "freedom of action" when considering others. Then we avoid doing actions that may harm others.
   We do actions that help other, which in turn may also result into helping us.
   The "caring" (which you mentioned) happens in this case too. We care about others too (childs, parents, etc), and get cared too.
   If *everyone* lives this way, the chances that we will die are much less than in the first 2 cases.

Given all that, we can say that in the case (1) the chances of death are the highest, while in the case (3) chances of death are the lowest. Thus (3) is the most **life-sustaining** formula.
Keeping this in mind, lets look at the "evolution" part to see what evolution does with sustainable/unsustainable forms of life.

### Evolution

By evolution, all forms of life transform consistently.
**Unsustainable forms die out or transform into more sustainable forms.**
So, by evolution, we (humanity) are also naturally advancing from unsustainable (1 and 2) to more sustainable form (to the case 3).

Side note: "Considering others" (case 3) requires us to sacrifice a part of freedom, to prevent ourselves from harming others.
It explains why we eventually created rules, laws to limit ourselves.
They all fit into natural evolution - steps of transformation of humanity from less sustainable to more sustainable life species.

Where we are generally: Unfortunately, we can generally say that humanity is in the case 2. It still exists more than it should. To prove it - look around - wars, robberies and other acts of violence still happen *every day*.
Suicides also happen (1), yet they take less lives than wars/etc.
Also we can see actions fitting more into case 3, but we are far from saying that humanity mostly fits the case 3. We haven't advanced to it yet.

### Sum up

With all that information, we can say that:
To become a more advanced and sustainable species (civilization), we (humanity) need to care about others, consider others.

Natural evolution's laws brought us to this point. And if we don't advance more into it - the humanity extinction is inevitable and is matter of time (human self-destruction or cataclysms will happen eventually).

This theme may go longer and can jump into many other aspects; but I hope this text gave you enough points think (and perhaps answer your own question).

Right now I would sum this up (constructively) this way: we need to consider/care about others in order to become a more **advanced** life-sustaining (species) civilization, and lessen the chance of death/humanity extinction.

You may sum-up other ways - would be very nice to see them!

Thanks for reading!

---

About the interesting question in comments:

> "Also, how would you explain, say, firemen, who risk their lives
> because they care? That certainly doesn't help them survive?"

Of course, that wouldn't help the firemen to survive. But it makes "humanity" more sustainable.

Take a look from evolution's point of view, which keeps life-sustaining formulas... and plays with whole *species* (not individuals).
Previously a human risked and saved more lifes than his own. That means this recipe helped to sustain life more, so this **formula will be repeated**, unless it becomes useless or starts to harm more lifes than it saves. Evolution works this way.
Of course you can add more personal reasons why firefighters safe lives... and those reasons will also be naturally part of the *same* evolution...

Comment: Thanks for putting in your answer, but I was looking for an answer in the face of a (hypothetical, yet possibly attainable) situation where people can live solely on the basis of market transaction. So this question has a moral/existential side to it.

Comment: @Ajax, got it. I've written this answer from evolution's point of view, and in a more general context. Will try to answer based on the context you provided as soon as I have more time (though seems like we already have good answers). In any case, thanks for your amazing question, it triggered deep thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't read about Camus, I'll try to answer the basics related to your question, which I think will help.

> If we take the World as absurd - without any meaning or end result,
> and believe in no such thing as God or afterlife (taking Camus' stance
> in Myth of Sisyphus), why should anyone, fundamentally, care about
> anything or anyone?

Even if you don't believe in God, I think you do believe in your parents, friends, relatives and the gadget you are using right now. I think you are getting something good out of that belief. In that case, no one can say that what you have said is not entirely true. A few years ago I tried to answer a similar question.

[If all of us are going to die one day why should we care about the feelings and emotions of others?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/if-all-of-us-are-going-to-die-one-day-why-should-we-care-about-the-feelings-and/47605#47605)

Answer (score 1):

The question is good, but can be straightforwardly clarified with reference to general philosophy. If there is no inherent meaning, then there is no inherent meaning to caring about another person. If there are no intrinsic values, then there is no intrinsic value to caring about another person. If there are no real obligations, then there is no real obligation to care for anyone, etc..

Are we missing something if we do not love and are not loved, even in an indifferent and cold society/universe? That may be what you're getting at, and it deserves a more nuanced answer than I am capable of.

Comment: Your answer is OK so far as it goes, but a more detailed discussion and perhaps some useful references would improve it a great deal.

Comment: It is like relativity: there is no absolute here or there, but things still move and fall. We have to deal with the universe not having a center, let alone it not being the Earth. Similarly, we have to deal with a lack of moral absolutes, let alone not being privileged and certain of right and wrong. But pain still hurts, and abuse is still wrong.

Comment: you seem to want to replace talk of rights etc. with claims that someone hurt me @ScottRowe is that right? seems a little facile, especially with moral relativism

Comment: The idea was that we might not want to hurt people because we can relate to the experience of pain. So we don't need an absolute telling us harm is wrong, we already know that.

Comment: ok yeah, that's absolute true thanks @ScottRowe

Comment: The +1 is for para 1. As for the following, as others have said it could be expanded or (IMHO) removed

Comment: ok well i'll take your word for it @Rushi

Answer (score 0):

We care due to pragmatic reasons, not by altruism.

As individuals, our final goal is to survive (any other goal is subject to being alive). Our probabilities of survival increase if we survive as a group, so we care about the rest, about every member. Therefore, in practice, the survival of the individual is subject to the survival of the group (that's why from time to time we, as a society, could agree to kill someone or put others in jail).

So, if you want to survive, you need to care about the rest. If you want to reduce your probabilities of survival, you can stop caring about the rest. Teach your son to be an unpleasant person, to care about nobody, and the probabilities he'll end in jail or get dead will increase dramatically. The more sincere and caring you are about the rest, the more your probabilities of survival are.

Comment: And this is precisely how evolution produces altruism.

Comment: Yeah, altruism that has a cause is still altruism, unless the individual is themselves consciously doing this in a calculated way for their own benefit...

Comment: Therefore altruism is a consequence. Altruism is not the cause of caring for others. We try to survive and that produces altruism as a consequence. What's the issue?

Comment: This argument looks fishy.  Why should one care about one's own survival?  Also, how would you explain, say, firemen, who risk their lives because they care?  That certainly doesn't help them survive.  It might indeed, however, be good for the group, but that's just begging the question given the question is why one should care about the group.

Comment: @HWalters "Why should one care about one's own survival?". See Maslow hierarchy of needs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs . Needs are expressed not only instinctively (the body demands food), but also rationally (I grow tomatos in order to eat them).

Comment: But you're arguing this: "If you want to survive, you need to care about the rest."  It's a bit flimsy; so I shouldn't be a violent criminal because I should want to survive; you haven't told me why I should want to survive.  But if that is the logic, I should also not be a police officer or a fireman; if I shouldn't be a criminal lest I wind up in jail, I shouldn't be an activist either; and if being nice to others helps accomplish something, so does convincingly faking being nice.